# how to Set display none in print pages based on condition in vue.js using css or js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am working in vue framework , i am working currently to print the webpages for my application. I need solution for one condition. I have addressed it below.

```
<template>

      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
        <div
        v-for="report in reports"
        :key="report.property"
        :class="['Section1', { 'non-print-css' : noprint }]">
          <div class="Icon" id="printReport_AId" v-if="isOverview">
             <font-awesome-icon :icon="report.icon" @click="printWindow()"/>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="logo"> this text should  be none when printing . if the section1 is none in screen. </div>
      </div>
</template>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               timestamp: ''
            },
            created() {

            },
            methods: {
              printWindow() {
      const curURL = document.location.href;
      history.replaceState(history.state, '', '/');
      const originalTitle = document.title;
      document.title = '. ';
      window.print();
      document.title = originalTitle;
      history.replaceState(history.state, '', curURL);
    },

     computed: {
       noprint() {
      const printicon = document.getElementById('printReport_AId');
      if (printicon.style.display === 'none') {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
      },
   }

            }
         });
      </script>
<style>
.non-print-css {
  // i have to set the display none for logo when its printed.
}

</style>
```

I have two div class

1. section1
2. logo.

condition:

- If section 1 display none  then when i print the page, the logo
  should not be printed.

  I have added condition in computed to check if the section display is
  none if it is true it should execute the css where we set @print.
  logo display is none.

  I need a proper solution either in css or in js

Answer (score 0):

You can apply print specific styling using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@media), and specifically

```
@media print {
    .non-print-css {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be executed only when the condition passes or else this will be generic to full webpage. and i need the logo to be removed in print pages but this will remove the report icon .

Comment: You can condition the class to apply it only on elements you want, when you are fulfilling the conditions you require.

Answer (score 0):

1. "If section 1 has display none" ... means that the element is rendered but not shown you have to give your `section1` a `v-show` directive not a `v-if` ... which when set to `false` (`v-show`) your element will have `display : none`.
2. " then when i print the page, the logo should not be printed"... so if `section1` `v-show` is set to `false` we are not going to print right .... on this case we should create a variable in our data and bind that to `section1` (`v-show`) so when that variable is `false` then the element has `display : none` so we don't print .... lets call that variable `isSection1` ...now on our method only if `isSection1` is `true` then we print ... here how it should be :

```js
data: {
    isSection1: false, // false means section1 has display : none
    timestamp: ''
  },
  methods: {
    printWindow() {
     // only if section1 doesn't have display : none
      if (this.isSection1) {
        const curURL = document.location.href;
        history.replaceState(history.state, '', '/');
        const originalTitle = document.title;
        document.title = '. ';
        window.print();
        document.title = originalTitle;
        history.replaceState(history.state, '', curURL);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="section1" v-show="isSection1"> </div>
```

Comment: no this is not the case i wanted, if i right click and give print option then it should not print

Answer (score 0):

I passed through here looking for a way to conditionally render a component but keep the space when it's not been rendered.
After passing from here I found this awesome publication that explains 3 options available in VueJS.

So, here you are [enter link description here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/vue-show-hide-elements/#1-hiding-using-v-if)

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it .partially but the element id is null , the event is not listened

1. Add the v-bind to logo class.
2. Add mounted() and computed () as below.

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('print', this.noprint);
    },

computed(){
    noprint() {
        const printicon = document.getElementById('printReport_AId');
        if (printicon != 'null') {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
  },
```